# Partition a SELECT result by percentage randomly with a new flag column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will keep it simple by saying I have a `SELECT` statement that returns all the subscribers information and let's say this statement returns 5000 records.

I would like to split these results so that:

1. 10% of those subscribers will be flagged as group A
2. 5% flagged with group B
3. The rest (85%) flagged with group C

I would like to have the group everyone belongs to in the result. That is obvious though I suppose.

And of course each subscriber should be only flagged with one group only. So we cannot have two records of subscriber "John" belonging to both groups B and C.

I would also like the percentages to be chosen randomly and not necessarily top 10%.

Comment: Are the groups assigned once or are they reassigned every time you make a select query?

Comment: So, if, for example, you get `1%`, `90%`, and `9%`, it will be OK, right?

Comment: what criteria would be use to group subscriber?

Comment: No criteria whatsoever. And no, I would like to partition them 5%, 10% and 85%. That means if there are 100 people, 10 will be in group A, 5 in group B and 85 in group C.

Comment: @rogaos No I just would like to assign them once.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  src.Column1, src.Column2, ..., 
        --src.RowNum, src.Cnt,
        CASE 
            WHEN src.RowNum * 1.00 / src.Cnt <= 0.10 THEN 'A'
            WHEN src.RowNum * 1.00 / src.Cnt <= 0.15 THEN 'B'
            ELSE 'C'
        END AS Category
FROM
(
    SELECT  *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowNum,
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS Cnt
    FROM    dbo.MyTable pd
) src
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some commands to create a new table that you can join with yours in your select query. If you would like to have all of the information in the new table, you can use the results of this table to create a new view or something.

When I say [count of 10%], I mean 500 if there are exactly 5000 records, a select statement if the table has inserts and deletes, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE subscriberGroup(SubscriberID [type], Grp [type]);
/* Inserts 10% random with A */
INSERT INTO subscriberGroup 
    SELECT SubscriberID, A FROM Subscriber ORDER BY rand() LIMIT [count of 10%];
/* Inserts 5% random with B. Make sure the count is 5% of original, not remaining. */
INSERT INTO subscriberGroup 
    SELECT SubscriberID, B FROM Subscriber WHERE SubscriberID NOT IN (SELECT SubscriberID from subscriberGroup) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT [count of 5%];
/* Inserts rest random with C */
INSERT INTO subscriberGroup
    SELECT SubscriberID, C From Subscriber where SubscriberID NOT IN (SELECT SubscriberID from subscriberGroup)
```

Now, you can have

```
SELECT [your select statement] JOIN subscriberGroup USING(subscriberID)
```

to get the desired result.

My SQL might be a bit rusty, but the general idea should work.
Obviously, the creation of this table will be slow, what with all of the order by rands, but since you only have 5000 records and are only doing this once, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: when I run your first INSERT I get a "Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'." error. Can you please check that?

Comment: did you change the `[count of 10%]` for a real number?

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez I'm trying but can you help calculate the count of of 10% from the original table?

Comment: SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(\*)\*.10) FROM Subscriber

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Windowed functions to acomplish that:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN RelativePercentRowNumber<= 0.10 THEN A ELSE
    CASE WHEN RelativePercentRowNumber<= 0.15 THEN B ELSE C END END AS Group

FROM(
    SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [your criteria])/ COUNT(1) OVER(ORDER BY [your criteria]) AS RelativePercentRowNumber
    FROM subscribers
) AS RankedSuscribers
```

Comment: `SELECT 1/2 AS ColA, 1.00 / 2 AS ColB`

Comment: There is no need to nest `CASE` expressions here. Just use a searched `CASE` with multiple `WHEN` clauses.